# Why having .shared.GWT and .client.GWT?

Tags: gwt

Since the Javadoc doesn't make clear the reason for having [com.google.gwt.core.**shared**.GWT](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/shared/GWT.html), which seems to contain a functional subset of the [com.google.gwt.core.**client**.GWT](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html), what's the reason for the former to exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As its name suggests, `shared.GWT` is usable on the server-side. `GWT.create()` doesn't support much things yet but will soon support I18N for instance, and its pluggable.